# Time for last meal if Tisha B’Av is on Sunday

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, tisha-bav, meal-seudah

If Tisha B’Av is coming on Sunday,
when or what time is the last meal for Shabbat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Havdallah after Tisha B'Av](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18101/havdallah-after-tisha-bav)

Comment: The latter part of your question is answered in point four of [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75396/7539), with the reasoning discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73872/beginning-fast-of-tisha-bav-during-shabbat?rq=1). (As distinct from the first part of your question, answered at WAF's link.)

Comment: No, they are talking about Sun. night, and my is Sat. night.

Comment: Yes, this is the same case. As you can see in the answer there,  as well as the [question I linked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/what-happens-when-tisha-bav-falls-out-on-shabbos), when the fast begins on Saturday night then Havdala is pushed off until Sunday night when the fast ends. (Though, as it says there, the blessing on the flame _is_ made on Saturday night, and no besamim is used either Saturday night or Sunday night.)

Comment: Anyway, unless the answers are expected to depend on one another or something, you should ask separate questions as separate question posts. But also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18101/havdallah-after-tisha-bav doesn't ask about havdala Sunday night: it asks about havdala either night; so your havdala question is a duplicate of that.

Comment: no intention to argue, you don't understand my question, and just remove my questions.  if I have answers, I don't need to ask.  they are talking about Sun.  and you argued there too about duplicate.  you can do whatever you want

Comment: there are many places to ask

Comment: This question has three closure votes as a duplicate of the other. Five and it's closed to answers. I edited out the part that's a duplicate so it doesn't accrue the last two and you can at least get answers to your meal question. You're welcome. As for the havdala question, you'll find that it's answered in the other page. And to the extent it's not, feel free to ask it (but not bunched together with a completely separate question).

Answer (score 2):

The last meal for Shabbat must end before [sunset](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/zmanim_cdo/jewish/Halachic-Times.htm), since the fast of Tishah B'av begins at sunset.

As aish.com writes [here](http://www.aish.com/h/9av/oal/48964976.html)

> Although any food may be served, including meat and wine, and zemirot
>   may be sung, the mood should be somewhat subdued.
>
> A person should not say that he is eating in order to have strength to
>   fast, but he may think this.
>
> **One must stop eating and drinking before sunset, since the fast begins
>   at this time. People should be reminded about this, as it is unlike a
>   regular Shabbat.**

Comment: @mbloch I actualy thought of doing just that, but decided not to c&P the whole thing b//c the first 2 parts were not part of the question, although important. I figured, when anyone clicks the link and reads #14 they will get that part too.

Comment: Hey feel free to rollback. My view on these is that anyone asking part of the question might as well get the full answer because they might not have thought of asking but will likely find it helpful